# TomEE Microprofile: microprofile-config.properties ignored

Tags: apache-tomee, microprofile, eclipse-microprofile-config

i'm having problems getting config values into my microprofile app. I have created a `META-INF/microprofile-config.properties` file like this:

```
configEntry=HelloWorld
```

I've got a simple test class like this:

```
import javax.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import javax.enterprise.context.Initialized;
import javax.enterprise.event.Observes;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.Config;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.config.inject.ConfigProperty;

@ApplicationScoped
public class ConfigTest {

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "configEntry", defaultValue = "missing")
    private String configValue;

    @Inject
    Config conf;


    public void init(@Observes @Initialized(ApplicationScoped.class) final Object init) {
        System.out.println("configEntry = " + configValue);
    }
}
```

I run this on TomEE MP 8.0.10 (downloaded standalone binaries). But whatever I do, `configEntry` is always 'missing' and when I debug-inspect the Config instance, I can see that there are 3 ConfigSources loaded (SystemPropertyConfigSource, SystemEnvConfigSource,TomEEConfigSource) but none is containing any entry for `configValue`.

I have also tried to create my own ConfigSource via `META-INF/services/org.eclipse.microprofile.config.spi.ConfigSource`. Same problem here: My test ConfigSource never gets included in the list of ConfigSoruces.

Is there any kind of secret (TomEE flag) to make this work? Did I miss something crucial, or is TomEE simply not supporting microprofile-config.properties (any longer)?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem:
This was due to an incompatible maven build configuration. All guides and tutorials I found usually specify the *pre-build* location of the file, not the location they must end up in the `war` file/dir. I did put them into the correct pre-build location, but maven placed them 'wron' (inside /META-INF/ not WEB-INF/classes/META-INF).

So, here for all with a similar confusion, *after the build* this is where the files must reside to be found:

```
microprofile-config.properties: /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
spi services directory: /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/
spi custom ConfigSource text file: /WEB-INF/classes/META-INF/services/
```